# how to nest a C function inside a MuJS object

Tags: javascript, c, embed

I needed to extend my C app with a scripting language so I tried MuJS, it's written in simple C, but it lacks documentation about specifics. Digging through the code I couldn't figure out how to do this basic task of creating a simple object with a function inside it.

**expected result:**

```
myobject: {
    myfn: function () {}
}
```

I tried this but it resulted in an "uncaught exception".

```
    js_newobject(J);
    {
        js_newcfunction(J, myfn, "myfn", 2);
        js_setproperty(J, -2, "myfn");
    }
    js_setglobal(J, "myobject");
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this with multiple unrelated programming languages? This clearly isn't C.

Comment: @Lundin this is entirely C, MuJS is an embeddable JS engine written in C, for C. The Code is entirely C. https://mujs.com/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned it, MuJS is poorly documented. You must consider switching to a better documented and widely used alternatives such as [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/luajit.html). Look at an example [here](https://gist.github.com/klgraham/6d4f937abf39e56d48381a3c40369920) .

Comment: it has to be JS, i like the syntax and i've written a lot of code for it for years, porting it is a pain, I've tried lua before (on awesomewm), didn't work for me too good. another condition is that the embedded engine should be tiny, simple, light, ..., i've tried duktape but even that was too bloated and cumbersome for my case :(((

Comment: That will be difficult to you use a badly documented library . You can try something like [QuickJS](https://github.com/bellard/quickjs). Or look at [that](https://v8.dev/docs/embed)

Comment: QuickJS looks promising, I'm gonna give that a try, the 210KiB is attractive, that's what I really liked about MuJS in the first place, small footprint. Thanks for introducing me to it. :))

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something else wrong, because the code you wrote should work as expected.

Here's a full example with your code that compiles and runs without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mujs.h"

void myfn(js_State *J)
{
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        js_State *J = js_newstate(NULL, NULL, 0);

        js_newobject(J);
        js_newcfunction(J, myfn, "myfn", 0);
        js_setproperty(J, -2, "myfn");
        js_setglobal(J, "myobject");

        js_dostring(J, "myobject.myfn()");

        js_freestate(J);
}
```